# How to compile luabind with C++11?

Tags: c++11, xcode5, luabind

I have an existing project using Luabind.

When I activate C++11 support from Xcode5, the LUABIND_CPP0x flag gets enabled, which includes luabind/detail/index_tuple.hpp that does not exist.

I noticed others have the same problem, unsolved for a year: https://github.com/luabind/luabind/issues/16

Did anybody on StackOverflow ever managed to make this work? Should I use a fork/patch? If so, any pointer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just comment definition of LUABIND_CPP0x in luabind/config.h, because C++11 support isn't really ready.